# Is is possible to style in external domain iframe in 2020?

Tags: javascript, css, iframe

client push me to change the CSS styles of an external site which is included in an iframe. Is it possible to do that? I found topics from 2011 with a solution, but after I tried to do that with CSS, js, jquery - I think is not possible if the site is not hosted by the same domain.

Answer (score 0):

It's still not possible for security reasons. In order to allow this, you'd need control of both sites, and even then, you'd be potentially opening yourself up to allowing XSS attacks on the target site. Your best bet would see if the target site has an API that you could pull data from and display on your site with whatever styling you want. That's a separate topic altogether though.